# How to represent an function parameter as an 2D array of objects on class diagram?

Tags: methods, parameters, uml, class-diagram

Is this a right way to show the UML class diagram for the below code

```
public class Test {
  Map<String, Map<String,Double>> bestOutput;
   private Obj[] testMethod(Weight[][] input) {
   }
}
```

I have a Test class and I also have  Obj class and Weight class.

[image: Please find the tried class diagram]

Is this class diagram correct for the above mentioned code snippets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You explicitly write the types, or me there is no problem, I allow that in BoUML

Comment: Just give that as answer, @bruno It's fine with UML specs too, not just your tool :-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian done ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this class diagram correct for the above mentioned code snippets?

yes this is correct, and fortunately allowed by the tools

---

I profit of that question to also show the representation of the parameterized classes and the binding classes, if I use your example that can be :

[image]

even if in C++ we do for instance `typedef Map<String, Double> String2Double;` rather than `class String2Double : public Map<String, Double> { ... };` (in BoUML to stereotype the class `<<typedef>>` produces that definition by default)